# Searched record first then the rest of the result set

Tags: mysql

I have a query where I want to output the desired record first then the rest of the result set.

I have a list of news items with a "read more" beside each item.

When a user clicks a "read more" link they are brought to the news page where I want the news item they chose (Lets just say its id = 1 for now) then I want the rest of the news items to be output afterwards sorted by date.

I have so far:

```
"SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY(id, 1), newsdate DESC"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you just need a UNION query:

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=1
UNION (SELECT * FROM news WHERE id<>1 ORDER BY newsdate DESC)
```

be sure to include second query between ( ).

Or you can also use a trick like this:

```
SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id=1 DESC, newsdate DESC
```

Comment: you're welcome :) i also edited and added a second solution, see what you like more

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to construct something to that effect, but personally I would just fall back onto two queries;

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=$id
```

And then;

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE id<>$id ORDER BY newsdate DESC
```

If you require a single result set to pass to your view, then you can concatenate the two.